# Validating XML by clicking a button in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, validation, button, xsd

So what I want to do is validate an XML file against an XSD file by clicking a button. My program already gives me the path to both of these files.

It seems to me if I want to validate files there's no way around using `ValidationEventArgs` and `ValidationCallBack`. I have no idea how to use those with a button.

Maybe this question is really simple but I couldn't find anything helpful using Google.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx

Comment: I have and I can't say it helped me. But thank you anyway!

Comment: Then I don't understand your problem. You have an XML and an XSD file. You know how to validate the XML with the XSD one by loading the files into and `XDocument` and a `XmlSchemaSet` (second example in the link). Do you have a problem with creating a button click event? Or with the XML validation itself?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about validating an XML file using a *button*. I guess the button click event has something to do with it. I'm really sorry about that vague description, but if I was able to word this better, I wouldn't have asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the two things:

1) in your code, create a new method to validate the XML. You can inspire yourself from [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx), load your XML Document into an `XDocument` and your XSD into an `XmlSchemaSet` and validate the first one with the second one using the `XDocument.Validate()` method

2) Create a button in your IDE and add a click handler. Depending on your technology, WinForms or WPF it will be slightly different. Then call your method in the Button_Click() handler method that was created for you.

Comment: Click handler, that's what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.